# Como hacer reload en vista madre al borrar registro en Popup

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

tengo el siguiente problema...

En una ventana madre abro un popup desde un icono, donde tengo unos registro de informacion, pero en la ventana madre manejo la informacion y necesito que al borrar un registro del popup se me actualize la ventana madre...

Este es el codigo al eliminar un registro.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btndeletehour').click(function(){
            var datos=$('#frmdeletehour').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"Deletehourshift.php",
                data:datos,
                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){
                        window.opener.location.reload(true);
                    }else{
                        alert("Fallo al enviar la peticion.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

El codigo si hace ejecuta la accion de eliminarme el registro y actualizar el popup pero no logro actualizar mi ventana madre, puse el codigo de window.opener pero no funciona de todas maneras.

Codigo Deletehourshift.php

```
<?php
    $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','psb_smt');

    $idProdu=$_POST['idProdu'];
    $Minutos=$_POST['minutos'];
    $idProduLost=$_POST['idProduLost'];

        $sql1="UPDATE psb_smt.psb_produccion SET psb_tptreg = psb_tptreg -'$Minutos' WHERE id='$idProdu'";

        $sql="DELETE B FROM psb_smt.losttime B WHERE B.id = '$idProduLost'";

        echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);
        echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    header('Location: PopUpDetail.php?id='.$idProdu.'');
?>
```

Comment: Luego de ejecutar tu peticion por ajax, estas esperando recibir un valor "r==1"
Pero en tu archivo de php no estar devolviendo ningun valor solo redireccionando a una pagina.

Prueba poniendo en lugar de header('Location: PopUpDetail.php?id='.$idProdu.'');
 return 1;

Answer (score 0):

puedes modificar tu código para que en el `success` tratar los casos exitosos, y luego en el `error` los errores que pueda retornar tu aplicación de backend.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btndeletehour').click(function(){
        var datos=$('#frmdeletehour').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"Deletehourshift.php",
            data:datos,
            success: (r) => {
                window.opener.location.reload(true);
            },
            error: (r) => {
                alert("Fallo al enviar la peticion.");
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Saludos!